# Add a second recipient in DocuSign signing process

Tags: python, python-3.x, docusignapi

I changed some DocuSign [Sample code](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/code-examples/quickstart-request-signature-email) to add a second recipient during a signing process. With the purpose of the user of my site signing and another (2nd) person hopefully getting an email requesting a further signature of the document. However my code is not working and I don't know if I'm adding the second recipient correctly:

```
with open(os.path.join(app_path, file_name_path), 'rb') as file:
    content_bytes = file.read()
base64_file_content = base64.b64encode(content_bytes).decode('ascii')
document = Document(
    document_base64=base64_file_content,
    name='Example document',
    file_extension='pdf',
    document_id=master_id
)
signer = Signer(  # this works on its own
    email=signer_email,
    name=signer_name,
    recipient_id='1',
    routing_order='1',
    client_user_id=client_user_id,
)
signer2 = Signer(
    email='secondperson@example.com',
    name='Some Guy',
    recipient_id='2',
    routing_order='2',
    client_user_id=client_user_id,
)
sign_here = SignHere(
    document_id=str(master_id),
    page_number='1',
    recipient_id='1',
    tab_label='SignHereTab',
    x_position='195',
    y_position='147')
signer.tabs = Tabs(sign_here_tabs=[sign_here])
envelope_definition = EnvelopeDefinition(
    email_subject='Please sign this document sent from the Python SDK',
    documents=[document],
    recipients=Recipients(signers=[signer, signer2]),
    status='sent'
)
api_client = ApiClient()
api_client.host = base_path
api_client.set_default_header('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + access_token)
envelope_api = EnvelopesApi(api_client)
results = envelope_api.create_envelope(account_id,
    envelope_definition=envelope_definition)
envelope_id = results.envelope_id
recipient_view_request = RecipientViewRequest(
    authentication_method=authentication_method,
    client_user_id=client_user_id,
    recipient_id='1',
    return_url=base_url + '/docusign-return',
    user_name=signer_name,
    email=signer_email
)
results = envelope_api.create_recipient_view(account_id, envelope_id,
                                             recipient_view_request=
                                             recipient_view_request)
```

The "secondperson@example.com" address has been added to DocuSign and I activated their DocuSign account. When I run this code the signing process works for the first user. However there is no email sent to "secondperson@example.com" and the document does not appear on the second person's DocuSign "action required". What am I doing wrong?

**Update**
The document status says "waiting for others" on the DocuSign sandbox, but when I go to the second account there is nothing under "action required".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Several issues that I see:

### `client_user_id` attribute means embedded signer

Since the second signer has the `client_user_id` attribute set, they are being treated as an embedded signer. As a result they will **not** receive an email invite to the signing ceremony.

If you want the second signer to be a `remote signer` (receive an email invite from DocuSign for the signing ceremony), then remove the `client_user_id` attribute.

Eg

```
signer2 = Signer(
    email='secondperson@example.com',
    name='Some Guy',
    recipient_id='2',
    routing_order='2',
)
```

### Signers do not need DocuSign accounts

In your question you say that

> The "secondperson@example.com" address has been added to DocuSign and I activated their DocuSign account.

but (generally speaking) signers do **not** need DocuSign accounts. (There are some corner cases where they do such as a Part 11 compliance signing.)

#### Don't use the same `client_user_id` for multiple signers

Sometimes you do want more than one embedded signer for an envelope. When you do, don't use the same `client_user_id` for more than one signer. It's bad form. Use each signer's `id` within your web app. If you don't assign ids in your web app, then use the signer's email as the client user id. If you don't have their email, then use `name@example.com`.

#### Added: API authentication for the signing ceremony

Since signers don't pay and don't need a user account on DocuSign, how does a developer's application call [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) to obtain the signing ceremony URL that the signer will use?

The answer is to use a "system account" -- create a user within your DocuSign account that generically represents either the application or a department. Eg sales@your_company.com.

Then, create a DocuSign access token by using the JWT grant to impersonate the sales@your_company.com system user.

Your application uses the resulting access token to call the [EnvelopeViews:createRecipient](https://developers.docusign.com/esign-rest-api/reference/Envelopes/EnvelopeViews/createRecipient) to obtain the signing ceremony URL.

Depending on which user sent the envelope, the system account may or may not need administrative privileges.

Comment: But don't you need an account ID to start the signing ceremony? Isn't the account ID associated with a person in DocuSign?

Comment: Does the RSA private key need to be in PEM or DER format? It just says "binary" in the API. So I'm guessing it is not in text format.

Comment: I created a new question concerning the RSA key.